# How can I get express-sitemap to generate a sitemap using Express Router

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get express to dynamically generate my sitemap for my nodejs project using express-sitemap. I seem to not understand the code properly since my app.js file has the basic code in it, but I think the router is not passing the individual routes to the sitemap.

This is my app.js file with code directly taken from express-sitemap:

```
// REQUIREMENTS
require("dotenv").config();
require('./src/connect/mongodb');
const   express         = require("express"),
        app             = require('express')(),     
        bodyParser      = require("body-parser"),
        mongoose        = require("mongoose"),
        methodOverride  = require("method-override"),
        nodemailer      = require("nodemailer"),
        expressSanitizer= require("express-sanitizer"),
        passport        = require("passport"),
        LocalStrategy   = require("passport-local"),
        path            = require('path'),
        multer          = require('multer'),
        slugify         = require('slugify'),
        mailchimp       = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing'),
        request         = require('request'),
        https           = require('https'),
        flash           = require('connect-flash'),
        multerS3        = require('multer-s3'),
        aws             = require('aws-sdk'),
        compression     = require('compression'),
        expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
        cors            = require("cors"),
        xoauth2         = require("xoauth2"),
        session         = require('express-session'),
        cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser'),
        map             = require('express')(),
        sitemap         = require('express-sitemap')(),
        
        
// MODELS
        Blog            = require("./models/blog"),
        User            = require("./models/user"),
        Portfolio       = require("./models/portfolio"),
        Resources       = require("./models/resource");

// SETUP
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true, limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// SESSION + PASSPORT LOGIC
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        httpOnly: true
    } 
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser  = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

// ROUTES LOCATIONS
const   indexRoutes         = require("./routes/index"),
        blogRoutes          = require("./routes/blog"),
        hostingRoutes       = require("./routes/hosting"),
        portfolioRoutes     = require("./routes/portfolio"),
        insiderRoutes       = require("./routes/insider"),
        accountRoutes       = require("./routes/account"),
        designRoutes        = require("./routes/design"),
        marketingRoutes     = require("./routes/marketing"),
        contactRoutes       = require("./routes/contact"),
        seoRoutes           = require("./routes/seo"),
        downloadRoutes      = require("./routes/download");

 // ROUTE INDEX
 app.use("/", indexRoutes);
 app.use("/blog", blogRoutes);
 app.use('/hosting', hostingRoutes);
 app.use('/portfolio', portfolioRoutes);
 app.use('/insider', insiderRoutes);
 app.use('/account', accountRoutes);
 app.use('/design', designRoutes);
 app.use('/marketing', marketingRoutes);
 app.use('/seo', seoRoutes);
 app.use('/contact', contactRoutes);
 app.use('/downloads', downloadRoutes);

sitemap.generate4(app);
console.log(sitemap);


// PORT INFORMATION
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server has started on port " + port);
 });
```

the console.log output produces this:

```
Sitemap {
  my: {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1',
    hideByRegex: false,
    sitemap: '/Users/andrewbuccellato/GFA/sitemap.xml',
    robots: '/Users/andrewbuccellato/GFA/robots.txt',
    route: [Object: null prototype] {},
    cache: false,
    sitemapSubmission: false
  },
  map: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _XMLwork: [Function (anonymous)],
  _TXTwork: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

And the sitemap page returns this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"/>
```

From this route in my index.js file (Referenced from my app.js)

```
// SITEMAP
router.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res) {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    sitemap.XMLtoWeb(res);
});
```

Can someone help me with what I am missing and why its not generating the sitemap like it would be expected?

Comment: I ran a console.log on my router stack and realized that how I have set things up it is showing as undefined. Can anyone help me figure out why my app.js setup would do this if I am using the express rotuer?